# Angular: Copy markup to external tag

Tags: angular

I am integrating the markup of an Angular-App A into another application B. This works fine. Now I want to "project" the content/markup of a component from application A into an html-tag in application B - which is obviously not part of our application.

Is this somehow possible? I was playing around with ViewChild and createEmbeddedView - but this doesn't seem to work for target-containers which are outside of the application:

```js
@Component({
    selector: "ebc-app",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild("clone") private template;
    @ViewChild("targetFooterContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) private container;

    constructor(@Inject("ISOLATED_RENDER_COMPONENT") public isolatedRenderComponent: string) {
    }

    private cloneTemplate() {
        this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
        // container is undefined here
    }
}
```

Comment: the HTML content, you mean?  i.e - do you want to project just the template HTML? Or the HTML as it is rendered by the component? Or the entire ViewRef with all its associated properties plus markup?

Comment: yes, without breaking eventhandlers and so on.

Comment: Sending the HTML template source as it is written in the component (but not as it is rendererd) may be easy, but anything else would be pretty difficult. Is the other app an angular app?

Comment: no it's not - the other application can be anything.

Comment: Yeah that sounds challenging. Perhaps someone has written a wrapper that can package and export a single component as a standalone HTML+CSS+JS package that can be hosted elsewhere, but even then you'd have to somehow isolate it form all its dependencies. Unless your templates are comprised of very little bindings/events, its final rendering will be dramatically different than its markup.  And if you've ever looked at transpiled typescript -> javascript code... extracting it from that mess would be a nightmare. So it would definitely have to be something that happened during the app build